# PT100, MAX31865 Calculation and Circuit Theory Problem

Tags: circuit-design, rtd

I have designed a 2-wire RTD circuit using MAX31865. The circuit based on application circuit. But I have a serious problem about the REF resistor and excitation current. In the datasheet, Maxim Integrated says that a reference resistor equal to four times the RTD's 0 celcius resistance is optimum for a platinum RTD. Therefore, a PT100 uses a 400R reference resistor.

[image]

The reference resistor current also flows through the RTD. So, Bias Voltage=2V, R=Rref+Rrtd(@0 Celcius), R=400R+100R=500R. Then, I=V/R=2V/500R=4mA. But, 4mA is causing self heating on PT100. Because the excitation current 4mA > 1mA.

I changed the REF resistor as 4k. I expected that excitation current almost equal to 1mA. But the circuit is freaking. I set the 100 Celcius on RTD simulator and I see the 650 Celcius on a related software (you know MAX31865 is a RTD-to-Digital Converter). Why this happenning?